# Sorting algorithms using void pointers , how can I do it?

Tags: c, sorting

i'm new in this forum , so.. let's explain what I need to do.
First of all , it's a home work , on this I've to create a schedule. But it's not a normal schedule , or a simple schedule, I need to do it with only one void pointer variable , to store all the memory.

So everything that I should need, I need to consider that I can only save variables inside the void pointer, and after it I need to use pointer arithmetic to access everything inside the void pointer. And I can only create pointer variables , and this one can only store memory adress .

So I decided to put only two variables , called name and number. Just to made this more easy to do. And named my void pointer by "pbuffer".
After it I create two structures , one to save all my variables , and another one to save the name and number.

Alright I got it , I finished the homework , But now , I need to implement this , put in sorting algorithms , like Bubble sort ,  Selection sort , Merge sort , Quick sort and insertion sort.

at this point, I've no idea , what I need to do!
for example : How can I sort the names by alphabetical sort ?

[my code in github](https://github.com/BrendonHenrique/AED1/blob/master/agenda.c)

Comment: What you need to do is visit stackoverflow.com's [help], take the [tour], and learn [ask] questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In alphabetic order (or lexicographical order), you need to use the *strcmp* string function.

Back to the main subject: the idea behind using the void pointer is to create generic code in C.

Assuming you have an array of the type *void* *, you can assign values to it by simple doing a typecast. However, if you want to assign an *int* value, you need to assign an *int* pointer to it:

```
int x = 3;
void *a = (int*) &x;
```

Doing that in String is even easier, since its beginning is a pointer to *char*:

```
char s[] = "Hello world";
void *a = (char*) s;
```

When you do *strcmp(s1, s2)*, you get, as return:

- -1, if s1 is behind s2 in lexicographic order;
- 1, if s2 is behind s1 in lexicographic order;
- 0, if s1 and s2 are the same string.

Hope that helps you get started!